# Set Bootstrap dropdown menu to 100% width of web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a sub-menu on my Bootstrap-driven web page.

In the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x7ehtscp/)**, if you click the first `Bla`, you will see a dropdown appear.

Is it possible I could span the dropdown 100% width of my web page? Currently it's set to `min-width: 700px`.

Here is my **HTML**:

```
<div id="wrap">

          <div class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="navbar-header">

                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar first"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar second"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar third"></span>
                </button>

              </div>
              <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left ">
                  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                      <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Bla</a>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <div class="yamm-content"> <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left"> <li><a href="#">Bla</a></li> <li><a href="#">Bla</a></li> <li><a href="#">Bla</a></li> <li><a href="#">Bla</a></li> </ul></div>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Bla</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Bla</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->

          </div>
        </div>
```

& **CSS**:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  /* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
}

/* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
#wrap {

  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* ==========================================================================
   Author's custom styles
   ========================================================================== */

.navbar-inverse
{

    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-top: 4px solid #C6252C;
    background-image: none; 
    padding-top: 80px;

}
.navbar-inverse ul li ul 
{

    background-color: #C6252C;
}

.navbar-brand
{
    color: white !important;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: white;
    padding-bottom: 18px;
}


.yamm-content .navbar-nav>li>a{
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
    color: white;

}


.navbar-brand
{
    padding: 7px;
}

.navbar-toggle
{
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent !important;
}


.navbar-toggle:not(.collapsed) span.first
{
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top: 6px;
    position: relative;
}

.navbar-toggle:not(.collapsed) span.second
{
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(-45deg);  
    top: 0px;
    position: relative;
}

.navbar-toggle:not(.collapsed) span.third
{
    display: none;
}



.yamm .nav,
.yamm .dropup,
.yamm .dropdown,
.yamm .collapse {
  position: static;
}
.yamm .navbar-inner,
.yamm .container {
  position: relative;
}
.yamm .dropdown-menu {
  left: auto;
}
.yamm .dropdown-menu > li {
  display: block;
}
.yamm .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
  left: 100%;
}
.yamm .nav.pull-right .dropdown-menu {
  right: 0;
}
.yamm .yamm-content {
  padding: 20px 30px;
  *zoom: 1;
}
.yamm .yamm-content:before,
.yamm .yamm-content:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
  line-height: 0;
}
.yamm .yamm-content:after {
  clear: both;
}
.yamm.navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu:after,
.yamm.navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu:before {
  display: none;
}
.yamm .dropdown.yamm-fullwidth .dropdown-menu {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
@media (max-width: 969px) {
  .yamm .dropdown.yamm-fullwidth .dropdown-menu {
    width: auto;
  }
  .yamm .yamm-content {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  .yamm .dropdown-menu > li > ul {
    display: block;
  }
}

.dropdown-menu {
  min-width: 700px;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus{
 background-image: url(img/arrowup.png);  background-repeat: no-repeat;   background-position: 50% 29px; background-color: #222 !important; border: 0 !important;
}

 .dropdown-menu{
    border: 0 !important; -webkit-box-shadow:none !important; box-shadow:none !important; border-radius:0 !important;
}

.navbar{border-bottom: 0 !important; margin-bottom: 0 !important;}

.navbar-nav>li>a {
padding-top: 5px;
}

.navbar-brand{position: relative;
TOP: -163PX;
float: right;}




@media (min-width: 768px) {
 .navbar-brand{  
position: relative;
TOP: -120PX;
float: right;

 }
 .navbar{
 height:127px;
 }

}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
 .navbar-brand{  
position: absolute;
TOP: 8PX;
text-align: center;
float: left !important;
 }

    .dropdown-menu{
    padding: 0 !important;
min-width: 0 !important;
overflow: hidden !important;
    }

   .yamm-content{padding-left: 30px;}

    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
    background-image: none;  

    }

}

.navbar-collapse{
MAX-HEIGHT:350PX;

}
```

Comment: Apologies. I added a `2` to my URL. Here's the correct one: http://jsfiddle.net/x7ehtscp/

Comment: move dropdown menu outside of the list item so it's parent has full width

Comment: Thank you, @Brian, can you possibly show this in a Fiddle, if possible? :-)

Comment: Why you are using dropdown class. when you are already using Yamm?